# Sharing Spring beans accross multiple servlets

Tags: spring

I am kind of new to spring, My requirement is to have users login through multiple servlets,

ex: all kinds of users goes to Dispatcher Servlet but Admin goes through a different servlets to ensure additional security, How would I share beans defined in Dispacher servlet Spring context beans to other servlets in same web application context.

also I like to have one more servlet for accesing Ajax requests,

All these servlets should share same HttpSession and beans, Will be more helpful to see a sample configuration code.

Answer (score 3):

You have 3 ways:

1- Use `ContextLoaderListener` to create a parent context, your serlvets would become children of that context., and define your beans in the parent context.

Check this [link](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#context-create)

2- the other way you have is to load the other servlet's xml file manually, like this:

```
ApplicationContext context =
                    new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:application-context.xml");
Person person = (Person)context.getBean("person");
```

3- and you can also import your servlet beans into other servlet using this:

```
<import resource="classpath:application-context.xml"/>
```